# setTimeout() work only 2 times

Tags: javascript

this is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=change;
var i=0 ;
function change()
{
    var images = new Array('1','2','3','4','5','6');
    document.getElementById('baner').src = obrazy[i];
    i++
    if (i == images.length)
    {
        i=0;
    }
}
setTimeout(change,1000);
</script>
```

I want make simple slider but setTimeout do my script only 2 times. Yes, I have element with id baner. I dont know what is wrong with that.

Comment: How about `setInterval()`? It's magic!

Comment: Actually it works 1 time only. Second call from window.onload or vice versa. So use setInterval instead

Comment: Just move `setTimeout(change,1000);` into the end of `change`

Comment: `setTimeout()` only calls your function once after the time has elapsed. Use `setInterval()` for continuous calls.

Comment: try to add log() to confirm your function call

Comment: Ok, my bad. It works! :D

Comment: @dedronek It’s actually better to put the `setTimeout` you’ve written into the end of the `change` function. Only that way will your `window.onload` work correctly and make any sense.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling `change` only twice, once in the handler of `window.onload`, and once after a timeout of 1 second.

**You may be looking for `setInterval`** instead of `setTimeout`:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var i=0 ;
    function change() {
        var images = new Array('1','2','3','4','5','6');
        document.getElementById('baner').src = obrazy[i];
        i++;
        if (i == images.length) {
            i=0;
        }
    }
    setInterval(change,1000);
    change();
}
```

Comment: Or they put the setTimeout in the correct location and it works... :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `setInterval()` method which calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

```
window.onload=change;
var i=0 ;
function change()
{
    var images = new Array('1','2','3','4','5','6');
    document.getElementById('baner').src = obrazy[i];
    i++
    if (i == images.length)
    {
        i=0;
    }
}
setInterval(change,1000);
```

`setTimeout()` method calls a function after a specified number of milliseconds and stop.